# Clear the screen stack in an iOS app

Tags: ios

I have *SplashScreen -> Sign Up -> Sign In -> MainScreen* screens. And in the MainScreen it's not necessary to remember all screen stack (I mean I can return to Sign Up/Sign In screens, but I should not have this possibility). How can I close unnecessary screens? Is it good approach when developing for the iOS UI?

Comment: So are you using a `UINavigationController` or what?

Comment: yes, I use UINavigationController -> so I have all screens stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using UINavigationController:

```
 //Pop back to the root view controller
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

 //Allocate and init the new view controller to push to
 NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc] init];

 //Push the new view controller
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: I need to have access for example to the Sign In screen only one time. (before I leave it)

Comment: Then i guess setViewControllers, as indicated by @H2CO3, will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a navigation controller to push these views onto the view controller stack, this would be a good point to pop back to the root view controller. Check out the docs for UINavigationController.

However, given that you're trying to handle initial app authorization, a better pattern might be to present your MainScreen view controller as the root view controller, and then use a modal view controller stack to handle sign up/sign in.

tl;dr: You should review the docs for UINavigationController and UIViewController. Pay particular attention to the difference between pushing view controllers and presenting modal view controllers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

An even clearer approach without the need of manual popping and pushing:

```
NSArray *vctrls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[MainViewController new]];
[navController setViewControllers:vctrls animated:YES];
```